# как получить список новых контактов скайп?

Tags: php, skype, skype-web-sdk

необходимо получить список новых контактов которые добавились ко мне. 
пока получилось только достать авторизованные контакты.
кто подскажет, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что я нашел. Это работает только если вы недавно добавили контакт (в течение последних 30 дней)

1. [Получить список сообщений](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/pthistoryconversation).
2. Найти в истории сообщений, по шаблону, например: "Hello, $name, I'd like to add you as a contact", первое сообщение.
3. Извлечь, временную метку сообщения.